# Как привязать домен к Centos 6?

Tags: centos, dns

Интересует инструкция для полных "чайников". В вопросе все написано, допустим, для домена abc.cd и ip сервера 1.1.1.1 (пример).

Пожалуйста, помогите.

Comment: Тебе нужно установить пару пакетов. Для работы с доменом. И далее настроить их. После этого сделать выход из системы и войти уже под доменным пользователем. Для того чтобы всё работало без запросов sudo предварительно нужно доавить доменного пользователя в sudoers. Не забудь про синхранизацию времени ntp, samba.

Comment: krb5-server и winbind. Первая ссылка из гугля https://it-community.in.ua/2013/01/vvod-v-domen-servera-pod-upravleniem-linux-ce.html/

Answer (score 1):

Нужно на DNS сервере (bind-named) создать зону или если в инете, то зарегистрировать у регистратора домен, а если только для одного компа, то в /etc/hosts.

Comment: Вот меня и интересует вопрос как, для приведенного мной примера.

Comment: я описал в краце 3 примера: локальный сервер DNS, файл hosts и регистрация домена. какой именно интересует?